# include template within jade's html

Tags: express, pug

I would like to know how to 'include templateName' within a jade template if i am using the dot notation in jade to use actual html tags.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/header.css')
  body.
     <div class="logo-container">
            include someTemplate
     </div>
```

Doing the above example will display the text 'include someTemplate' and not the template itself.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The include won't work inside a Plain Text block as it's a Jade statement and not a JavaScript expression, so it would be easier for you to shift the Plain Text blocks line by line so you can use both:

```
body
  | <div class="logo-container">
  include someTemplate
  | </div>
```

The thing that makes this more complex is the wrapping `<div class="logo-container">`.  This could also work if you have large chunks of raw HTML to output and don't want a lot of pipe characters:

```
body
  div.
    (raw html goes here)
  .logo-container
    include someTemplate
  div.
    (more raw html goes here)
```

If your template doesn't need jade/pug rendering (i.e. if it's just constant/static text) then you can use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) to output variables:

```
body.
     <div class="logo-container">
            !{someTemplate}
     </div>
```

This only works if you [read the template file](https://code-maven.com/reading-a-file-with-nodejs) in your router and pass it to the template as a variable. There are more complicated ways to dynamically render this, but by then you're just better off using one of the methods above.

Comment: @Graham The first example works although I'm not so fond of the | before every line. For the second example, could you provide an example of of loading up the template as variable in the routes?

Comment: @IanS I've just edited to give you another way to handle this and a link to an example of reading in a file.  We're probably at the point where you'll need to edit your original question with more details in order to give you specific advice (things like why you need to output raw HTML, what's in the included file, etc.).  If what is above doesn't work for you just reply to this comment and I'll comment on your original question with my questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the edits. Both of these examples have worked for me and I am a happy man with some working dynamic jade templates.

Comment: If possible, upgrade to pug as soon as possible in order to get the latest version.  It's worth it, and usually just requires renaming *.jade to *.pug and a few lines in app.js.

Comment: Good suggestion. There are also way more stack questions asked about pug vs jade